# C# Proxies keep refusing connection, weird port

Tags: c#, proxy, connection, port

Basically i'm making a proxy checker, and for some reason a ton of proxies are saying the connection was refused, while they work perfectly fine in my browser.

I noticed that the port in the error is not the port i was trying to connect to..

Say i was trying to connect to
60.5.187.109:3128
in the log it says
System.Net.WebException: Kan geen verbinding met de externe server maken ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Kan geen verbinding maken omdat de doelcomputer de verbinding actief heeft geweigerd 60.5.187.109:31245
(Can't connect to the server because the target computer has actively refused the connection.)
Notice how the ports are different?

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://google.com");
                        request.Proxy = proxies[cProxy];
                        request.CookieContainer = cookies;

                        HttpWebResponse req = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

The code snippet which is failing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there is a port forwarding option activated either in you're computer or the remote one

Also, how do you connect to the proxy and what you send to it ?

Another thing, .Net application uses automatically the system proxy if it's set ! did you check it ?

Comment: I am using the HTTPWebRequest class so the system proxy shouldn't even be used.

Comment: I think it uses it automatically ! so if you are setting the system proxy deactivate it and try

Comment: Also, use Wireshark and watch your network traffic, you will see if it's your computer who change the port or the remote destination